# Why do I get different results in these 2 SQL queries? Using AVG alone vs. when using over()

Tags: sql, group-by, window-functions, querying

Using `AVG()`:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    m.season,
    m.home_goal,
    m.away_goal,
    AVG(m.home_goal + m.away_goal) AS overall_avg
FROM 
    country AS c
LEFT JOIN 
    match AS m ON c.id = m.country_id
WHERE 
    name = 'Belgium'
GROUP BY 
    c.id, m.season, m.home_goal, m.away_goal
```

Using `OVER()`:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    m.season,
    m.home_goal,
    m.away_goal,
    AVG(m.home_goal + m.away_goal) OVER() AS overall_avg
FROM 
    country AS c
LEFT JOIN 
    match AS m ON c.id = m.country_id
```

I get different results for the average column. I don't understand what the difference is.

Comment: Please tag a RDMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the absence of the `where` criteria in your second query (just a mistake in your question?), they are fundamentally different.

By using the `group by` clause, the results are grouped by the distinct unique combinations of the grouped columns, collapasing all like-rows into one, and for each of these groups, the `avg()` - and any other aggregated functions also - operate on the rows in these groups individually.

In the second query, no grouping of rows occurs and so every row is returned. The use of the `avg()` function with an `over` clause is referred to as a *window* function, where the window in question (basically a qualifying range of rows) is specified by the *over* clause; `()` denotes the window is the entire result set and each row gets the average of all rows.

Answer (score 2):

In your first `GROUP BY` query, `AVG(m.home_goal + m.away_goal)` is an *aggregate* function, which will return the average for each group.  In the second non `GROUP BY` query, `AVG(m.home_goal + m.away_goal) OVER()` is a *window* function which will return the average over the entire *table*.